# Running two v4l2loopback devices with their individual properties

Tags: v4l2, v4l2loopback

Working with v4l2loopback devices I can run these two virtual devices:

a) running the preview image from a Canon DSLR via USB through v4l2loopback into OBS:

```
modprobe v4l2loopback
gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc fd=0 ! decodebin name=dec ! queue ! videoconvert ! tee ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278688/canon-dslr-video-loop-back-using-v4l2loopback-and-edsdk-liveview), and it works.

b) Streaming the output of OBS into a browser based conferencing system, like this:

```
modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1 video_nr=10 card_label="OBS Cam" exclusive_caps=1
```

Found [here](https://srcco.de/posts/using-obs-studio-with-v4l2-for-google-hangouts-meet.html), this also works.

However, I need to run **both** a) and b) **at the same time**, which isn't working as expected. They are interfering, it seems they are using the same buffer the video flips back and forth between the two producers.

What I learned and tried:
A kernel module can only be loaded once. The v4l2loopback module can be unloaded using the command `modprobe -r v4l2loopback`. I don't know if loading it a second time will be ignored or unload the previous one.

I've tried to load the module with `devices=2` as an [option](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/wiki/Faq#q-i-need-to-use-several-loopback-devices-simultaneously-how) as well as different video devices, but I can't find the right syntax.

Comment: what exactly are "both things" and how don't they run? your quesion contains an enumeration of what works fabulously, but it lacks crucial inforamtion about what does not. it's not even clear what you mean with "individual properties".

Comment: Both shown v4l2 commands run on their own but when executed while the other is running they interfere with each other and seem to write to the same buffer even if (as i assume) different devices are set.

Comment: 1. please update the question to contain any additional information (rather than providing clarifications in the comments) 2. "interfere" is a very broad term. i don't know what you mean by it in this context. 3. which commands are you talking about? `modprobe`? this command will load a module into the kernel (possibly with some parameter). you cannot load the same module twice (without unloading it first)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from your description ("the video flips back and forth between the two producers") it seems that both producers are writing to the same video-device.

to fix this, you need to do two things:

- create 2 video-devices
- tell each producer to use their own video device

## creating multiple video-devices

as [documented](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/wiki/Faq#q-i-need-to-use-several-loopback-devices-simultaneously-how) this can be accomplished by specifying `devices=2` when loading the module.

taking your invocation of `modprobe`, this would mean:

```
modprobe v4l2loopback devices=2 video_nr=10 card_label="OBS Cam" exclusive_caps=1
```

this will create two new devices, the first one will be `/dev/video10` (since you specified `video_nr`), the 2nd one will take the first free video-device.
on my system (that has a webcam, which occupies both `/dev/video` and `/dev/video1`) this is `/dev/video2`

## telling each producer to use their own device

well, tell one producer to use `/dev/video10` and the other to use `/dev/video2` (or whatever video-devices you got)

e.g.

```
gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | gst-launch-1.0 \
       fdsrc fd=0  \
       ! decodebin name=dec  \
       ! queue  \
       ! videoconvert  \
       ! tee  \
       ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video10
```

and configure obs to use `/dev/video2`.

or the other way round.

just don't use the same video-device for both producers.
(also make sure that your consumers use the correct video-device)

Comment: To name both devices, you can use `card_name="One,Two"`. Same with `video_nr=10,11`.

Answer (score 14):

As there is an already accepted answer, I assume your problem has been solved. Yet, I was quite newbie and couldn't set the syntax even after the answer above (i.e. how to set video2)

After a bit of more search, I found the [website](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) that explains how to add multiple devices with an example.

`modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=3,4,7 card_label="device number 3","the number four","the last one"`
Will create 3 devices with the card names passed as the second parameter:

- `/dev/video3`-> device number 3
- `/dev/video4` -> the number four
- `/dev/video7`-> the last one

When I was trying to use my Nikon camera as a webcam and OBS as a virtual camera for streaming, to have full control of naming my video devices was important. I hope this answer will help some others, as well.